# Javascript initialization and functions implementation into a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to copy [@szimek's](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) signature pad...

I always get confused on how to implement a pure JavaScript functions and initialization(such as shown in the code below) into a Vue component.

I am new to Web Development, I know my question is silly but I hope you bear with me :)

```js
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
  penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
});
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');
var cancelButton = document.getElementById('clear');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');

  // Send data to server instead...
  window.open(data);
});

cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  signaturePad.clear();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.signature-pad {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  Draw over image
</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/jnW4Qz/Grumpy_Cat_920x584.jpg" width=400 height=200 />
  <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="save">Save</button>
  <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<script>`, it's useless in Vue component template, instead use it like a package, `import SignaturePad from 'signature_pad'`.

Initialization code goes to `created` or `mounted` hook.

DOM shouldn't be accessed directly if possible in Vue. If this needs to be done, refs need to be used instead. Event handlers can be set in the template:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas ref="padRef" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <button @click="save">Save</button>
  <button @click="clear">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Contrary to legacy JS, components are supposed to be destroyed at some point. A proper cleaup needs to be done. It can be something like:

```
mounted() {
  this.signaturePad = new SignaturePad(this.$refs.refPad, ...);
}
destroyed() {
  // some cleanup
  this.signaturePad.off();
},
methods: {
  save() {
    var data = this.signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
    ...
  },
  clear() {
    this.signaturePad.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I did the same earlier but I dunno why it wont work :P, Thanks tho. Btw, Is it possible to add image to a canvas? I'm trying to have a soft copy of a document and draw a signature over it.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't use this package myself. signaturePad.fromDataURL likely does what you ask about.